# initWithFormat not working in xcode objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm following this tutorial I found online on how to make a calculator in xcode. I am using version 3.2.6 of xcode and here is the function that is giving me problems:

```
-(IBAction) calculate
{
    float x= ([textField1.text  floatValue]);
    float c= x*([textField2.text floatValue]);

    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c];
}
```

I get these compiler errors on the line with label.text:
Expected ':' before ';' token  and confused about earlier errors bailing out.

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Do I have to include a special header file to use initWithFormat? or is this a syntax error?

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code you posted. Could it be somewhere else? (The errors would cascade down the code and make it look like there was a syntax error here, when there wasn't.)

Comment: Don't see anything wrong really.  My guess is the culprit is elsewhere and this is a red herring.  To answer your question directly, no you don't have to include a special header.

Comment: I would recommend that you use the class method: +stringWithFormat: instead, like this: label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f", c]; By using this approach you don't really have to worry about memory management, as class methods autorelease the object for you. When creating objects using +alloc and -init, you own it and are therefore responsible for releasing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have an invisible character in there somewhere.

I frequently end up with the wrong kind of line ending.  The easiest way to tell is put your cursor on a line and hit ctrl-a.  If the cursor bounces to the beginning of the previous line, it is an incorrect line ending.   Delete the line ending and hit return.

(In my case, it is due to a bit of neural hardwiring resulting from 20 years of emacs usage)

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was just some invisible character that was making go crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have you `NSLog` the `label` and `label.text` before `label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c];` ? Maybe there is something wrong with your `label`.